# Need to rewrite the code foreach to LINQ Query

Tags: asp.net

How to change the below Foreach to LINQ Query?
List showPopup = bizDraftOrder.GetDraftOrders(LocalUser.employee_id);

```
                    foreach (var D in showPopup)
                    {
                        item1 = new ListItem(D.HALO_LEASE_FLAG);
                        if (item1.ToString().Contains("Y"))
                        {
                            RadWindowManager1.RadAlert("You have exceeded for maximum vehicle count for        lease.", 400, 150, "Alert", null, null);
                            rbtSubmit.Enabled = false;
                            rbtReset.Enabled = false;
                            return;
                        }

                    }
```

Please tell me how to rewrite this

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have all your code to check if the solution works.
But in theory this should be your LINQ query you are looking for.

```
var item1 = showPopup.Select(D => new ListItem(D.HALO_LEASE_FLAG))
                     .FirstOrDefault(i => i.ToString()
                     .Contains("Y"));

if (item1 != null)
{
    RadWindowManager1.RadAlert("You have exceeded for maximum vehicle count for lease.", 400, 150, "Alert", null, null);
    rbtSubmit.Enabled = false;
    rbtReset.Enabled = false;
}
```

1. `"Select"` is performed on "showPopup" to create a new list of objects containing only the property "HALO_LEASE_FLAG".
2. `"FirstOrDefault"` is performed to the new list to find the first item that matches the conditions.
3. The condition is that the ToString() method of the element contains the string (to be more precise char) "Y".
4. If such an element is found, it is `assigned` to the variable "item1", `otherwise it remains null`.
5. Then it is checked if "item1" is not null, if it is not null your code will be executed

That means, if item1 is NULL, then nothing was found, this is due to the `FirstOrDefault`, it gives you the first item, and if it finds nothing it gives you `"Default"` so `NULL`

Comment: Thank you for the code Schecher_ 1,could you explain what is i in the item1 and also explain query for item1 as i am not aware of the LINQ quiries?

Comment: @SravyaDamodar i have added it in the reply